# If i call multiple useStates in a useEffect will they be batched or they will lead to performance issues?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

If i call multiple useStates in a useEffect will they be batched or they will lead to performance issues?

Example:

```
    useEffect(
    () => {
      setDate(date)
      setStartDate(startDate)
      setEndDate(endDate)
      setSelectedNodes([])
      setName('Test')
    },
    [dateChanged, startDate, endDate]
  )
```

Comment: As per https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation, they run in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong, but I've found that the [useReducer hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) makes this a little more manageable.

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'specialThing':
      return {endDate: action.endDate, startDate: action.startDate, ...etc}
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'specialThing', startDate, endDate, ...etc })
  }, [dateChanged, startDate, endDate])
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```